# no attribute error in python while importing other python file

Tags: python, import, attributeerror

i import another python file in my current python file. when i call function from imported python file it show `Attribute Error: module 'abc' has no attribute 'classify'`. how to solve this issue?

app.py

```
import abc
a=abc.classify(upload)
```

abc.py

```
def classify(data):
  app.logger.debug('Running classifier')
  upload = data
  image = load_image(upload)
  #load_image() is to process image :
  print('image ready')
```

please tell me what goes wrong in this. i use python version 3.7.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to 'abc' is a python standard library

https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html

So when you import it with `import abc`, you are actually importing the standard one, not your own module. So, either you choose another name for it or you do a relative import; if it's in the same path level of your other file you can do `import .abc`

But I recommend you to choose another name to avoid further issues

Answer (score 1):

Change the `abc.py` file to another name, it's a standard library.